# Text replacement not working in Office?

Tags: macos, text

I am talking about the text replacement function under system prefs/keyboard/text.

I have added multiple replacements, but they don't work in MS Office (Word, Excel, etc). Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word does not use apple's stuff for this, you set it up in word's own Tools > Autocorrect .

Comment: I am familiar with Word autocorrect, but I want Word to use the macOS text replacement. anyway to achieve this?

Comment: No.  Same with spellcheck.

Comment: Could it be that Office now integrates better with MacOS (but nevertheless somehow fails with text replacement)? Because when select "Show Substitutions" in the menu shown in [the other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363039/403240), there is button "Text preferences..." which actually leads to the MacOS system text replacement settings... However, despite this apparent integration, text replacement doesn't work for me in Outlook,

Comment: @Christoph. I think Outlook integrates (at least in theory), but Word, Excel, Powerpoint do not.

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook, make sure that "Text Replacement" is active.

[image]

Comment: This option isn't available in PowerPoint though